# adding parameters to a function

Tags: c++

Please tell me how to change the function so that I can pass an unlimited number of arguments to `const std::function<void()>& task`, and use them.

```
void GIF::Play(Graphics* g, HDC hdc)
{

    /*auto task = [&]()
    {
    
        this->draw(this->hdc);
    };*/
    Timer *mTimer = new Timer(std::chrono::milliseconds(100), [&] 
        {
            ++CurrentFrame;
            this->draw(hdc, CurrentFrame);
            std::cout << hdc;
        }, false);
    mTimer->Start();
}
void GIF::draw(HDC g, UINT CurrentFrame)
{


    Graphics graphics(g);
    GUID guid = FrameDimensionTime;
    gifBitmap->SelectActiveFrame(&guid, CurrentFrame);
    /*выводить кадры*/
    //gifBitmap->UnlockBits(&bitmapData);
    this->position.x = 50;
    this->position.y = 50;
    ::std::shared_ptr<::CachedBitmap> cbitmap = 
    PNGLoader::createCachedBitmap(gifBitmap, g);
    graphics.DrawCachedBitmap(cbitmap.get(), position.x, position.y);
    ++CurrentFrame;
    if (CurrentFrame > frameCount) CurrentFrame = 0;
    std::cout<< CurrentFrame << std::endl;


}
void GIF::Play(Graphics* g, HDC hdc)
{

    
    Timer *mTimer = new Timer(std::chrono::milliseconds(100), [&] 
        {
            ++CurrentFrame;
            this->draw(hdc, CurrentFrame); 
        }, false);
    mTimer->Start();
    
}
```

```
Timer::Timer(const std::chrono::milliseconds& interval,
    const std::function<void()>& task,
    bool singleShot)
    : mInterval(interval),
    mTask(task),
    mSingleShot(singleShot),
    mRunning(false)
{
}

void Timer::Start()
{
    mRunning = true;
    mThread = std::thread([this]
    {
        while (true)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mRunCondMutex);
            auto waitResult = mRunCondition.wait_for(lock, mInterval, [this] { return !mRunning; });
            if (mRunning && !waitResult)
                mTask();
            if (mSingleShot)
                mRunning = false;   
        }
    });
}
```

init:

```
Timer *mTimer = new Timer(std::chrono::milliseconds(100), [&] 
{
      ++CurrentFrame;
      this->draw(hdc, CurrentFrame); 
}, false);
mTimer->Start();
```

**I need to update the frame via hdc running in a timer in another thread, frames are added but there is no Bitmap update**

Comment: Can't be done. You'll run out of storage.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to do. Please give a more detailed example. The example you are showing does work if `task` is declared beforehand.

Comment: ***pass an unlimited number of arguments*** There will always be some limit.

Comment: You can pass at most zero arguments to a `std::function<void()>`.

Comment: As you expect `std::function`, you can still pass lambda which capture any number of extra parameters.

Comment: You (repeatedly) call the function with zero arguments, and never call it with more than that. Aside: you start a thread and never end it, even for a single shot timer, should the loop be `while (mRunning)`?

Comment: @Caleth, its for test right now)

Comment: @user17732522, for example, i want pass args in func. `Timer *mTimer = new Timer(std::chrono::milliseconds(1), task, false);
void task(int a )
{
    std::cout<<a;

}`

Comment: Yes? And where will that `int` come from?

Comment: Tactical note. You might not want `Timer *mTimer = new Timer(std::chrono::milliseconds(1), task, false);`. `Timer mTimer(std::chrono::milliseconds(1), task, false);` is usually more than enough and is much easier to manage.

Comment: @Caleth, sry, i mean `imer *mTimer = new Timer(std::chrono::milliseconds(1),** task(2)**, false);`

Comment: or maybe i can arg from **task** function and insert in lambda func.? `void task(int a ) { auto task = [&]() { std::cout << a << std::endl; }; }`

Comment: idk how its work

Comment: @Y0MMY Please add code samples to the question using the [edit facility](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71427833/edit) rather than posting them in comments where they can be very difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a lambda that calls your function with the desired arguments, e.g.

```
void task(int a) { std::cout << a; }

// ... elsewhere

Timer *mTimer = new Timer(std::chrono::milliseconds(1), []{ task(2); }, false);
```

Comment: is it possible to do this without a lambda function? I will pass the HDC parameter for rendering cachebitmap, it will not work via lambda

Comment: @Y0MMY Then you are likely not passing the `HDC` to the lambda correctly.  Or more likely, since the `Timer` is running in a different thread, the `HDC` is being destroyed before you can draw on it, or it simply can't be drawn on outside of the thread that created it. You need to provide a [mcve] of the actual problem you are having.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, i edit my ques with all details

Comment: @Y0MMY no, you did not provide "all details". What you posted is not a [mcve]. Where is the `HDC` coming from? Where is `Play()` being called from?

Comment: @RemyLebeau its first

Comment: @RemyLebeau calling from WM_PAINT

Comment: @Y0MMY Then you are going about this all wrong. The `HDC` is only valid within the `WM_PAINT` handler, you can't draw on it inside a threaded timer. And you might get multiple `WM_PAINT` messages between timer iterations. You should instead use the timer to prepare the bitmap you want the window to display, but not actually draw the bitmap on the window from the timer.  Signal the window to repaint itself whenever the bitmap changes, and let the `WM_PAINT` handler draw the current bitmap as-is.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you mean I need to get an array of frames and then output it in a timer?

Comment: @Y0MMY No, that is not what I said. Save the current frame as needed, and signal a repaint.  Have the timer update the current saved frame and signal a repaint. Every time a `WM_PAINT` is received, just draw the current saved frame onto the window.